# Automated input for gather verb using comma in the phone number

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to build a dynamic unique number with Twilio by doing: 55512345678,999. Where the first part is a Twilio number and the 999 is a code generated by my server.

On the server side there's a gather verb ready to listen to the 999 code and act accordingly. My problem is that when calling using the comma, sometimes the 999 code is entered too soon, before the call gets connected so the Twilio gather verb does not get to read the code. What I'm trying to do with this is to save the user the effort of inputting said code by providing the phone number containing the code already. Any idea on how to do this in a better way will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe that for each comma you enter in the number, the phone will leave a pause of a second. It might be the case that just leaving a couple more pauses might allow your TwiML to load and Twilio to listen to the dynamic code. Try something like the number `55512345678,,,999` and see if that helps.

Comment: No worries @AlejandroPerez! Did it work? If so, do please mark this as the correct answer so other people can see how to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: It did @philnash, however this is something that doesn't happen very often. So far I've seen it ~1 out of 15 calls. I just wanted to improve reliability :) On a side note, using the letter "p" instead of "," has the same effect. This was particularly useful when creating vcards for android 5.0.1 as when saving the vcard, it removes the comma from the number, leaving it like 55512345678999.